# GetPictInfo replacement Api in quartz 2D

Tags: deprecated, macos-carbon, quartz-2d, osx-leopard, quickdraw

how to get pict info without using deprecated call to GetPictInfo ?
Also, is there anyway to get pixmaphandle without using deprecated Api, i could not find any .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you relearn how to work with images on Mac OS X.  If you can handle a little Cocoa code, use the `NSImage` class.  Otherwise, use Core Graphics and the `CGImage` API.  Either one works.

Since `PixMapHandle` is itself deprecated, you cannot use it without using deprecated functions.  Use Core Graphics (Quartz) instead.